# AD Group Folder Access

Tags: permissions, active-directory, directory, subdirectory

I have two AD groups as Group1 and Group2. I add same user to these groups through windows application. I have folder say abc to which I attach AD Group1. In abc I create a child folder abcd and attach the AD Group2 by disabling inheritance property. When tried to access the folder with user credentials I can access abc but when try to access abcd folder got exception as access denied. What is the cause for this exception and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just test to see whether the user is member of groups 1 and 2....

Something like this:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
GroupPrincipal group1 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "group1");

if(group1 != null)
{
   bool userIsMemberOfGroup1 = user.IsMemberOf(group1);
}

GroupPrincipal group2 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "group2");

if(group2 != null)
{
   bool userIsMemberOfGroup2 = user.IsMemberOf(group2);
}
}
```

That way, you never need to enumerate **all** groups the user is a member of - only check with those groups that are of interest to you,

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I have used windows authentication mechanism where I don't need to send user credentials,AD automatically does it. But when the same user is present in two groups where one group is having access to parent folder and second group is having access to child folder then I am getting exception you don't have rights/permission.